# How to suggest hints to Rstudio for auto completion for my code?

Tags: r, rstudio

Normally if `a` is a data.frame then one can autocomplete the column names by doing `a$` *tab*. The *chunked* package has a nice feature where if you run

```
a <- chunked::read_csv_chunkwise("some.csv")
```

then when you type `a[` then *tab* then it will show a list of variable via autocompletion even though `a` is not a data.frame.

I was trying to replicate this for my own code but I couldn't find any relevant resources after googling for "rstudio autocompletion" and various other searches.

I note that `class(a)` returns

> [1] "chunkwise" "tbl"

I had a look at all the functions that belong to the S3 class "chunked" and I note that it has a method called tbl_vars, so I thought maybe that's what Rstudio uses to do the autocomplete.

So to test it out I tried

```
write.csv(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), file = "test.csv",row.names = F)

tbl_vars.test_auto_complete <- function(fs) {
  names(fread(fs$path))
}

test_auto_complete <- list(path = "test.csv")
class(test_auto_complete) <- "test_auto_complete"
tbl_vars(test_auto_complete)
```

> [1] "a" "b"

But then when I type `test_auto_complete` *tab* the auto-complete doesn't show the variables that I want.

How can we give hints to Rstudio to make auto-completion work?

Comment: That's not a feature of the package. It's an RStudio feature. You can do `a <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2); a$<tab>` or `a[,<tab>`. I suspect this is tied to the `[` function and relatives.

Comment: It is RStudio feature, see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion) for examples.

Comment: I know it's an RStudio feature. But chunked also managed to hint the rstudio to do it for their object. You see, the object a is not actually a data.frame or data.table. Please str(a), so how does Rstudio know what it's "columns" are even thoguh the "columns" are not present in the usually way that data.frame and data.table were presented

Comment: Again, I believe this is linked to `[`. RStudio probably does something similar to `ls(a)` (with some additional bells and whistles to distinguish lists and data.frames etc).

Comment: hopefully someone can come up with an example make autocompletion work for a user defined S3 class. Currently I am still scratching my head as to how chunked achieved it? Do I have to define all the dplyr methods? it's a mystery. I tried replacing the `.vars` for an object of the the chunkwise class and the autocompletion works by using the replaced values. So for chunekd it's tied to the definition of .vars but I can't find in the source what is does special with .vars

Comment: I do not see any use of `[` in your example.

Comment: @Roland have u tried chunked package as I have shown? If it's to do with [ then the best way is to find an example instead of keep saying the same point. "How" is it using [? An example that can other will be nice. I still can figure out how chunked does it.

Comment: No I haven't and I won't. As I said, this will probably work for any use of `[`, `$`, and `[[` for list-like structures. I've given an example above. I don't think you have to do anything as a package developer. However, you are free to study the source code of the chunked package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153129/discussion-between-xiaodai-and-roland).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For objects that inherit from the `tbl` class, RStudio does indeed call `tbl_vars()` to populate completions. (This is an RStudio-specific autocompletion system feature.)

In your example, the object you're creating does *not* inherit from `tbl`, so this autocompletion pathway doesn't kick in.

However, this form of 'ad-hoc' S3 dispatch (where you define S3 methods directly as code like this) is not detected by RStudio, so you won't be able to verify this with test code like this. You'll have to explicitly define and register the S3 method in an R package.

Alternatively, you can try explicitly registering the S3 method with something like:

```
registerS3method("tbl_vars", "test_auto_complete", tbl_vars.test_auto_complete)
```

for inline testing.